# why am i seeing this message "library not found for -lboost_system"?

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, boost-thread

I am trying to build a binary using a Makefile, however i am seeing this baffling error message "library not found for -lboost_system". The Makefile runs the following:

```
*g++ BookKeeper.o  OptionsBookKeeper.cpp -o OptionsBookKeeper -    I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/lib -lzdb  -lQuantLib -lpthread -lboost_system*
```

Within /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/lib resides the following libraries: libboost_system-mt.a and libboost_system-mt.dylib . These look fine with me, is there anything obvious that i have missed out?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the multi threaded build of libboost_system. So use `-lboost_system-mt`